# changing a value of a class pointer in const Class function gives an error in some compiler but not others

Tags: c++, pointers, undefined-behavior

I have below code and It gives an error as "segmentation fault"  in some compiler but for other compilers it gives "40" as output. Why is there difference?

```
#include <stdio.h>

class A{
    int *ptr;
    public:
    void set(int val) const;
};
void A::set(int val) const{
    *ptr = val;
    printf("%d", *ptr);
}

int main(){
    A a;
    a.set(40);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ptr is an uninitialized pointer. When you deference an unitialized pointer, it's undefined behaviour, anything can happen.

You should initialize ptr in the constructor

```
class A{
    int *ptr;
    public:
    A();
    void set(int val) const;
    
};

A:A()
{
    ptr = new int();
} 


A:~A()
{
   delete ptr;
}
```